# What does Leovold, Emissary of Trest & Teferi's Puzzle Box do to opponent's hands?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Case 1:

Player 1 has [Leovold, Emissary of Trest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeovold%2c%20Emissary%20of%20Trest%5d) and [Teferi's Puzzle Box](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%27s%5d%2b%5bPuzzle%5d%2b%5bBox%5d) on the Battlefield.
Player 2 starts with his draw phase and has one card in his hand.

I think he puts his card on bottom of his library and draws a new one.
However he is not able to take another.

Case 2:
Player 1 has Leovold and Teferi's Puzzle Box on the Battlefield.
Player 2 starts with his draw phase and has no card in his hand.

Therefore "nothing" happens with the Puzzle Box and he only draws a card. 
Am I right or did I miss something? Do you feel this combo is that strong?

Comment: Not all hope is lost here! There remains a priority window between the draw from the draw step and Puzzlebox forcing you to ditch your hand, where Player 2 could jam an instant speed kill spell on Leovold (or Puzzlebox, although the recovery will be slower).

A *really* cruel combo adds Geier Reach Sanitarium, because during the opponent's upkeep you could force them to draw and discard, with no priority between the two. Once you grind them down to 0 cards in hand (with the Puzzlebox or something else), Sanitarium truly locks them out of casting spells from hand ever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though the phrase "beginning of the draw step" suggests otherwise, those abilities trigger after the turn-based action of drawing a card for the turn.

> **504.** Draw Step
>
> **504.1.** First, the active player draws a card. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.
>
> **504.2.** Second, the active player gets priority. (See rule 116, “Timing and Priority.”)

Regardless how many cards Player 2 has in this case, they will draw a card, then [Teferi's Puzzle Box](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%27s%5d%2b%5bPuzzle%5d%2b%5bBox%5d) triggers, eventually resolves, then has that player put all cards on the bottom of their library.
[Leovold, Emissary of Trest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeovold%2c%20Emissary%20of%20Trest%5d) will prevent them from drawing any other cards, as they've already drawn a card this turn.

Comment: May want to add the part wher a "can't" always wins.

Comment: @NeilMeyer: It does play a part here, but it's a very basic rule that I choose to omit in answers for the sake of cleanliness. Nevertheless, [here's a link to the rule](https://rules.wizards.com/rulebook.aspx?game=Magic&category=Game+Rules#_ucRuleBookSelector__ucRuleBook_dlRules_ctl22_lblRuleCode) for anyone interested.

Comment: This combo is hilarious for all sorts of reasons. I love it.

Answer (score 3):

The draw happens at the beginning of your draw step, then the ability of Teferi's Puzzle Box is put on the stack. Therefore, Player 2 will draw a card, then put all his/her cards on the bottom of their library in any order and not draw any more cards.

Yes, it is very unfortunate.

Comment: Now i get it thank you! Didnt know you draw your card first. Damm that hurts.

Comment: @Fallender Be sure to accept an answer if one of them satisfies your question, by clicking on the check mark near the answer. You can always come back later and change the accepted answer if someone writes a better one.

Comment: @Rainbolt, roger that.